# Access form.vars.value in Symfony subform using Twig

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I am working on a Symfony 2.7 WebApp and I would like to use a custom Form Widget for one of the entites. The Widgets needs to access the `form.vars.value`. This works fine as long as the Widget is uses within the main form. But when using the Widget in a subform, `form.vars.value` is empty.

The classes used within the form:

```
class AdressBookEntry { 
    // The main phone number of this contact: Type PhoneNumber
    protected $mainPhoneNumber;
    //...getter and setter for mainPhoneNumber

    // An array of Addresses
    protected $addresses;
    //...getter and setter for addresses

    ...
}

class Address { 
    // The phone number of this address: Type PhoneNumber
    protected $phoneNumber;
    //...getter and setter for phoneNumber

    ...
}

class PhoneNumber {
    ...
}
```

The custom Form Types for theses classes:

```
// Custom FormType for AddressBookEntries
class AdressBookEntryType extends AbstractType {
    ...

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {  
        // Type 'phone_number_edit' is registered in services.yml
        $builder
            ->add('mainPhoneNumber', 'phone_number_edit', array(
                'label' => '...',
                ... 
            ))  

            ->add('addresses', 'collection', array(
                'label' => '...',
                ... 
            ));
    }
}


// Custom FormType for Address
class AddressType extends AbstractType {
    ...

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {  
        $builder
            ->add('mainPhoneNumber', 'phone_number_edit', array(
                'label' => '...',
                ... 
            ))  

            ...;
    }
}
```

The custom Widget for the PhoneNumberEdit

```
{% block phone_number_edit_widget %}
    ...
    {{ dump(form.vars.value) }}
    ...
```

The PhoneNumberEdit for the main form (representing the `AddressBookEntry`) works fine. The `dump` statement shows the content of the assigned `PhoneNumber` object.

Within the Subform of the `addresses` collection however, the `form.vars.value` variable is empty. The dump shows just `""`.

So, how do I access `form.vars.value` within the subform? How can the widget recognize wether it is being uses within the main form or a subform?

**UPDATE:**

Some additional information as asked in the comments:

@Jeet: As described before the dump shows an empty value/string: `""`

@DOZ: This is the Twig code:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}         
    {{ form_row(form.name) }}

    {{ form_widget(mainPhoneNumber) }}

    <ul data-prototype"{{ _self.addressItem(form.addresses.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}" >
        {% for address in form.addresses %}
            {{ _self.addressItem(address) }}
        {% endfor %}
    </u>

    ...
{{ form_end(form) }}

{% macro addressItem(address) %}
    <li>
        {{ form_widget(address.phoneNumber) }}
        ...
    </li>
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: can you show me the code where you dump form.vars.value in the subform ? (the twig template with all your code where you call the forms)

Comment: what do you get from `{{ dump(form.vars.data) }}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use value instead of form.vars.value

```
{% block phone_number_edit_widget %}
    ...
    {{ dump(value) }}
    ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either. The result is the same: The `dump` within the subform just shows `""`